# Git doesn't track changes in existing file

Tags: git

I must admit I'm still kinda a beginner with git.

I've got a .feature file for cucumber sitting here that I changed quite a bit in code.

I was ready to commit, here was my workflow, the commands I performed in order and the result:

**git status**

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   ../package.json

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   ../gulpfile.js
        modified:   ../package.json
        modified:   features/some.feature
        modified:   features/step_definitions/some.js
```

- **git add ***

  it does its thing
- **git status**

  On branch master
  Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
  Changes to be committed:
    (use "git reset HEAD ..." to unstage)

  ```
      modified:   ../package.json
      modified:   features/some.feature
      modified:   features/step_definitions/some.js
  ```

  Changes not staged for commit:
    (use "git add ..." to update what will be committed)
    (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)

  ```
      modified:   ../gulpfile.js
      modified:   ../package.json
  ```

  - git commit -m "my message"
  - git status
- **git add .**

  I did just just because I was trying out  * vs .
- **git status**

  Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
  Changes to be committed:
    (use "git reset HEAD ..." to unstage)

  ```
      modified:   ../package.json
      modified:   features/some.feature
      modified:   features/step_definitions/some.js
  ```

  Changes not staged for commit:
    (use "git add ..." to update what will be committed)
    (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)

  ```
      modified:   ../gulpfile.js
      modified:   ../package.json
  ```

So now I am wondering if this is saying my modified files some.feature and some.js isn't being picked up and staged?  It's not looking like my commit is picking up those changes??  Maybe I just misunderstood git here...

And I did a git add, why isn't it staging the gulpfile.js and package.json changes?  the package.json is not a new file, I commited that already in the past but the gulpfile.js is something new I introduced in my working directory.

Answer (score 4):

The reason it is not staging gulpfile.js and package.json is because they were not in the directory (or below it) when you did `git add .`, which only adds files in the current directory and below. If you `cd ..` and do a `git add .`, they will be added.